# How to set a PayPal connection to my packages website

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, cart

I have a website with a virtual money system. I need the user to buy some virtual money and I am planning to do it via the PayPal API. The user should choose a package and then pay and then get the virtual money in his account in the website. It is very similar to an e-commerce website.
Does any one know or have a link to an information about this topic?
Best
Jonathan

Comment: This seems a simple paypal integration. Have you checked paypal documentation?

Comment: Can you send me a link to the specific chapter? i pretty lost

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the url for API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api). Just select your use case..

Comment: oK, but how do i know what API good for me. i never use those api's before. do you know wher can i find example code?